# Почему не срабатывает JS-скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть: нужно словить шестой клик по кнопке (".cltr-button-next"), и привязать к нему действие: захватываем блок с класссом .lp-hero, у которого убираем класс .vib-size-midle и вместо него добавлем .vib-size-result

Вроде бы как несложно, но у меня почему-то не срабатывает.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function lastClick(){
  var iter = 0;
  var clCounter = document.querySelector(".cltr-button-next");
  clCounter.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(++iter == 6) {
      $('.lp-hero').removeClass('vib-size-midle');
      $('.lp-hero').addClass('vib-size-result');
    }

  });
};
lastClick();

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var iter = 0;
  $(".cltr-button-next").on("click", function(){
    if(++iter == 6) {
      alert('click '+iter);
      $('.lp-hero').removeClass('vib-size-midle');
      $('.lp-hero').addClass('vib-size-result');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lp-hero vib-size-midle">ipHero</div>
<button class="cltr-button-next">cltr-button-next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Опечатка в названии класса `cltr-button-next`, нужно `ctrl-button-next`. Ошибка в консоли браузера.